# Find a and b so that the function x(t) is a solution to the differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

When I have two unknowns, actually three because of t, how do I then find a and b so that they satisfy the equation where I have substituted x(t) and x'(t) into the equation? Normally gaussian elimination would be possible if I had two equations, but in this example we only have one equation.

[image]

**EDIT:** The left side of the equation can be simplified like this:
[image]

so the equation would look like this:

[image]

I don't know if that would help.

Comment: Can you see why you must have $b=-2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare the two sides of your equation.  You have exponentials in $t$ on both sides, so you need to have $b$ so you get the same powers of $e$.  Then the exponentials divide out and you will have an equation you can solve for $a$.

Comment: So you are saying that because the left side of the equation has -2 at the same place as b in the right side the equation, that b must equal -2?

Comment: That is correct.  To have the equality true at all times you need the exponential factors to match

Answer (score 0):

Given that $x(t)=\frac{1}{2}e^{-2t}$

Differentiating with respect to $t$,

$\frac{dx}{dt}=-e^{-2t}$

Now $\frac{dx}{dt}+4x=-e^{-2t}+2e^{-2t}=e^{-2t}=ae^{bt}\implies a=1$ and $b=-2$.